# Fixed element overlaps popup's scrollbar

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/xb4NK/1/

The page's `.tall` content is overlayed by invoked fixed fullscreen scrollable popup.
Popup container `#fixedPoster` has some `.tall` content (different from body's content) in it which is wider than the window size and taller too. By means of overflow rules, the `.tall` content of popup can be scrolled.

There is also a fixed `.fixSpeckle` element inside popup, sliding always-on-top sidebar of sort.

As you see in JSF, that `.fixSpeckle` overlaps the popup's scrollbar when window height is less than `.fixSpeckle`'s height. That's no good and my intent is to prevent that from happening.

Let's sum these requirements up:

- There is an invokable fixed fullscreen popup. When popup is invoked,
  the body's overflow is hidden.
- Popup is scrollable.
- Popup has some huge content in it, thus scrollbars appear.
- There is another fixed
  element `.fixSpeckle` inside a popup that can be taller than window size.
- Another fixed element `.fixSpeckle` should better not overlap the scrollbars of
  the popup.

I'd be grateful fot both suggestions on whether these requirements can in theory be fulfilled and on how to do it if the combination is possible.